# How to redirect http to https while the other folder stays http?

Tags: virtualhost, redirect, apache2

I have 2 folders, **CRM** and **my_website**.

The my_website can be access to https://example.com/ (it will change http to https), while the CRM is http://example.com/crm.
and this is my virtual host

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_website
    Redirect / https://example.com/

    Alias /crm /var/www/html/crm
</VirtualHost>
```

**my_website.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName Example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_website
 
    Alias /crm /var/www/html/crm

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sll.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private1.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is the CRM is changed to https, instead of http.

Comment: Why is it a problem that CRM changes to HTTPS? It should be preferable to use it over an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

That's right because you've listed Redirect directive globally for your VirtualHost that will affect every URL on that host. If you need to specify this for particular URL you have 2 options at least:

1. You can you location section like in this example: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
2. You can use .htaccess file in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

First [enable mode_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Next remove the following line

```
Redirect / https://example.com/
```

And try using  [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html) rule to set your https redirect instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^crm($|/) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: where to put this RewriteEngine?

Comment: In your 000-default.conf file instead of Redirect / https://example.com/